# Simulate a PayPal pending echeck upon purchase from the sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am having a really hard time figuring out how to simulate receiving an echeck from a customer through my company's sandbox store.  I set up a user with only as bank account (no credit card) from the paypal developer site, and am able to place an order from the test store. But, after I complete the order, the status is Completed in PayPal.  I want it to be pending so I can use the IPN simulator to simulate receiving the payment. Anyone have any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simulator has echeck-pending, echeck-declined, and echeck-completed built in already.  You could just use those.